# Type of this database

Tags: database

I have some code that contains some sort of access a database. It seems like [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) (it uses JSON to store on disk save, but lays in the application in memory though) in memory, but I am not able to find the type of it.

It both fits into definitions of some types and doesn’t fit at the same time.

[Database code](https://hastebin.com/raw/sowacacotu)

What type is this database?

Comment: That's from this, right? https://github.com/blockplacer/Revatry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code, it looks like a SQL database, because it's using tables, primary keys, and rows.  JSON doesn't necessarily indicate NoSQL.